# update sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, update, patching

What is the correct way of update SharePoint 2016, there are two packages for [updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715807(v=office.16).aspx#BKMK_2016) for sharepoint 2016

1. SharePoint Server 2016
2. SharePoint Server 2016 MUI/language patch

I have a sharepoint 2016 installed in development farm, can I go directly installs sharepoint server 2016 package  it redirects to me to a security update for SharePoint Server 2016:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a short answer,** The `(language independent - language dependent`) fixes are required to be installed with any sequence.

> **Important**: It is required to install **(language independent - language dependent)** fixes to fully patch a
>   SharePoint server as each SharePoint installation comes with a
>   language-independent component and a language-dependent component. If
>   additional language packs are added later (only) the language
>   dependent fix has to be applied again.

---

**What does that mean?**

**First,** In any case (`Only SP 2016 or SP2016 with Language Pack`), you must do the following:

- It's **mandatory** to install both fixes, the sequence does not matter!
- Run the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard after all fixes installed!

**Secondly** To install a new Language Pack **later** on a farm that already patched with Nov 2017 CU, you should do the following:

- Install the new Language Pack.
- Install the *language dependent* fix of the current CU installed (Nov 2017) again!!
- Run the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard

> **Note:** Nov 2017 CU includes Feature Pack 1 and Feature Pack 2

For more details check [November 2017 CU for SharePoint Server 2016 is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2017/11/14/november-2017-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/)

Comment: this means can i go for sharepoint server 2016 MUI/ language patch :nov 2017 if i will install a language pack after i finish installation of sharpoint 2016?

Comment: Check my updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install the latest CU for SharePoint 2016. As you mentioned in your question, November 2017 is latest CU (which include the Security Updates as well). You can install it on RTM version of SharePoint 2016.

For SharePoint 2016, MSFT make it easy for multiple Language installed environment, Now you need to download one exe file irrespective of language pack installed on your server. Now single exe file include fix for all languages no matter which language you select when downloading the package from the MSFT site. Before we have to download one package for each installed language pack.

You need to install the both files (language independent & language dependent as well). Order really doesnot matter, but make sure both package installed followed by running config wizard on all servers in the farm. Sometime you have to run the following pwoershell psconfig command to get the no action required status from the central admin.

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force
```

If you dont want to run the Config wizard from GUI then run the below powershell (thanks to Trevor)

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install
```

[November 2017 CU for SharePoint Server 2016 is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2017/11/14/november-2017-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/)

Comment: That psconfig command is incomplete. Always use `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`.

Comment: thank you for the input...but i mentioned the command when we ran the config wizard from GUI but still status of the server not says No action required....May be i was not clear....